# Instructions for combining some partitions using gparted, and some other questions

Tags: ubuntu, partition, gparted

(first time StackExchange Linux user here),

I have been using Linux Mint for quite a while now, and originally partitioned with only a little space for it (originally intended just to play around with it). Because of this, I have just used all my storage.

I have another 80 or so GB to add to it using gparted, but am inexperienced with the program, and don't want to break anything. My disk allocation looks like this:

[image: partition img]

As can be seen, Linux Mint is on `/dev/nvme0n1p5`, with 70 GB unallocated to its left. I would like to combine these.

In addition to this, windows is on `/dev/nvme0n1p3`, which I would like to remove. Is it safe just to right-click in gparted and delete it? (Everything is backed up on flash drive already.)

Would the combination process for the old-windows partition (if I delete it), be the same as for the unallocated 74.81 GB?

**Update:**
I have taken initiative, and uninstalled Windows completely. The partition table on gparted now looks like this:

[image: New Partition Table]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the *Partition -> Resize/Move* option in GParted to resize your partition. The *Resize/Move* dialog is very simple, you can simply resize the partition to the left by dragging the slider.

[image]
The only "problem" is you can't do this with a mounted filesystem so you'll need to use a LiveCD (Ubuntu installation CD has GParted so you can use that). Also when resizing to the left all the data will be copied to the start of the free space so it might take some time to finish. And backup your data before doing this, the resize/move operation is safe but things can always go wrong (you can lose power or the system can crash in the middle of copying etc.) so having a backup is always a good idea when working with storage.

Comment: Great! I'd already started with this process, and had encountered several errors. For one, I am getting a ``watchdog: BUG: soft lockup - CPU#0 stuck for 22s!`` when starting gParted. I had burnt the gparted iso to my flash drive just with ``right click -> burn to location`` option. Could  this have caused it?

Comment: Just solved the soft lockup issue. For anyone else searching for a solution to the same problem, I re-installed gParted as the AMD version. Then, when the start screen loaded, I pressed tab, and then enter. After a few seconds, everything booted normally!